# Is it possible to implement Scrum while building a Monolith?

Tags: domain-driven-design, microservices, scrum, monolithic

I am actually learning Scrum, and there is no recommendation for a particular app architecture.

I have the feeling that Scrum is designed to go with Domain Driven Design, and that every Sprint should map to a Bounded Context, which are better implemented with Microservice.

So I am wondering if Scrum can be fully implemented while building a Monolith ?

Comment: Scrum is not tied to any of those things.  Scrum is a management technique; it couldn't care less about how your software is designed.

Comment: Ok, but practically, it seems to be more appropriate to produce releasable feature at the end of a Sprint if that sprint's output is a microservice

Comment: Ah, I see where you're going with this.  Firstly, some features are too large to successfully complete in two weeks, even with microservices.  Forcing your architecture to conform to some arbitrary standard of "two week releasable features" is a case of the tail wagging the dog.

Comment: So "practically," if your definition of "releasable feature" is "something that the customer can see," I claim that your methodology forces you into making decisions about your architecture that you really shouldn't be making.  You should make architectural decisions because they are the right decisions to make for your software, not because you have two-week deadlines to meet.

Comment: Ok. I should be making some confusion on what could be the output of a Sprint. A book that I am reading "Essential Scrum" say it should be something with some Value for the customer, could you detail it please

Comment: Yes, that is what the scrum books say.  What I am saying is that, if you take that approach, you will eventually lose some of the benefits of maintaining a sensible architecture.

Comment: Ok, so practically, that thing with some value for the customer, what should it looks like, how does the customer get in touch with it ?

Comment: The same way the customer looks at any other feature.

Comment: I think you're missing the point.  Your architecture should be informing your design decisions, not some arbitrary sprint interval.

Comment: Ok Robert, thank you very much for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your definition of monolith. If you just mean a very large centralized system, this is completely possible (though one could argue against that architectural approach in general).

On the other hand, if you mean that there is a singular system designed in its entirety up-front and then built as one large deliverable, then no, Scrum is specifically an incremental approach to development and building in large phase-gates runs directly against Scrum.

Comment: I was blocking on what is meant by "potentially shippable", I though it MUST be something that can be ran and tested ALONE. But want it really means and how you run it is up to development team. They might be shipping a Microservice, a library, or just addition or even revision for a library, there is always a way to integrate it and run it, and see the added value.